# Excel function to auto-increment

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table in Excel.

Is there a way to auto-increment in excel to create like in "New Sub ID Expected" ?

```
ID     Dose     New Sub ID Expected

1      30mg         1A                
1      30mg         1A
1      50mg         1B
1      70mg         1C
2      20mg         2A
2      20mg         2A
2      10mg         2B
2      20mg         2A
3      10mg         3A
3      12mg         3B
3      15mg         3C
```

Comment: Will it ever go past `1Z`, and if so, should the next position be `1AA`?

Comment: No it will never past 1Z

Comment: Can you sort by Dose as well? That would make things easier. Basically so that the last instance of `2A` gets moved up one row.

Comment: See my update, I can sort this way

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion... I meant sorting by *both* ID and Dose.

Comment: I dont think i can. its one or the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the dynamic array formulas `UNIQUE` and `FILTER`:

```
=A2&CHAR(MATCH(A2&"_"&B2,UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:A$12&"_"&B$2:B$12,(A$2:A$12=A2))),0)+64)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you are incrementing with a number (so `1,2,3` instead of `A,B,C`), use the simpler:

```
=A2&MATCH(A2&"_"&B2,UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:A$12&"_"&B$2:B$12,(A$2:A$12=A2))),0)
```

which just drops the `CHAR` and `+64` from the original formula.

Comment: I am trying to implement a number instead of a letter. This is what i tried. =D2&CHAR(MATCH(D2&"_"&C2,UNIQUE(FILTER(D$2:D$12&"_"&C$2:C$12,(D$2:D$12=D2))),0)+51). But it returning a "4" as the first number

Comment: Change the `51` to `48`... but note, this won't work after you hit `9`... the next iteration won't be `10`.

Comment: A simpler option for a number is `=A2&MATCH(A2&"_"&B2,UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:A$12&"_"&B$2:B$12,(A$2:A$12=A2))),0)`. That will work to increment `9` to `10`.

Comment: Yeah the simpler option will work... `CHAR` should not be used if you want to increment numbers. Ignore my suggestion from before.